# Having issues with ES6 based multiple (React) Node.JS Module imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've been working on a React project and I'm having an issue trying to use ES6 to import several exported React node modules.

This is my code:

[image]

I should be able to include the **AddFriendInput** and **FriendList** from the **hello** folder without any issue. But I get this error when webpack/babel compiles:

```
ERROR in ./src/common/containers/Menu/indexRender.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../hello in /Users/markpaul/Documents/projects/patient-portal-app/src/common/containers/Menu
 @ ./src/common/containers/Menu/indexRender.js 122:13-35
```

The content of my **AddFriendInput.js** file is like so:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class AddFriendInput extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      name: this.props.name || ''
    };

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I use webpack with babel to transpile my files. My Babel config is:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"]
}
```

The only way I can get it to work is to do this:

```
import AddFriendInput from '../../hello/AddFriendInput/AddFriendInput';
import FriendList from '../../hello/FriendList/FriendList';
```

But as you can see, this looks horrible.

Can someone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create **home/index.js**

```
import AddFriendInput from './AddFriendInput'
import FriendList from './FriedList'

export { AddFriendInput, FriendList }
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

Rename `AddFriendInput.js` to `index.js` and after that you can import like this:

```
import AddFriendInput from '../../hello/AddFriendInput'
```

Comment: Tnx for the suggestion, that will work but thats not what I'm trying to do. I want to import multiple modules at one go using the root directory hello. i.e. import { AddFriendInput, FriendList } from '../../hello';

Comment: `export const AddFriendInput` <--- I believe `const` would cause a syntax error here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: FYI if taking the `home/index.js` approach, you can use Babel's [transform-export-extensions](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-export-extensions) plugin to make your code more concise. 

Example: `export AddFriendInput from './AddFriendInput'; export FriendList from './FriedList';`

Answer (score 1):

ES6 module doesn't automatically load nested directories/files

import by directory name (`../../hello`) implies that you have `hello/index.js`

### updates

you could just create home/index.js as @Sergey mentioned or there is a module named [auto-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-import) that watch your directory and update index.js for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not understand the commonJS.

if the `../../hello` is a folder, nodejs will find `index.js` file. so you must be have a file `../../hello/index.js`.

```
import AddFriendInput from '../../hello/AddFriendInput/AddFriendInput';
import FriendList from '../../hello/FriendList/FriendList';

module.exports = {
   AddFriendInput,
   FriendList
};
```